# call a function at a specific duration from a html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

i would like to call a function on an specific time from a html5 video.

```
<video id="vidplayer" height="605px" width="500px">
<source src="media.mp4#t=17,21" type="video/mp4" id="vidmedia"></source>
</video>
```

This video plays only betweens the seconds 17->21. At the 21 seconds i would like call an function that another video load at this time.

With ".onended" the function doesnt work.

```
var vidplayer = $("#vidplayer").get(0);
var src = "newvideo.mp4";
vidplayer.onended = function(e) {
        $("#vidplayer").find("#vidmedia").attr("src", src);
        vidplayer.load();
        vidplayer.play();
        };
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onpause` event, because the video isn't actually reaching the end, so it won't fire an `onended` event.

You could also try the `ontimeupdate` event, and check at what position the video currently is (`vidplayer.currentTime`)